# The process cannot access the file 'video path' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net-core, youtube, filestream

My project is about stream video in html page using tag video.
this tag's src is a url like "http://localhost:35162/Uploads/video".
that is a net core api service.

```
[HttpGet("vid")]
public IActionResult Get(string token)
{    
    var path = @"~/sample.mp4";            
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    return File(fileStream, "video/mp4");            
}
```

it works fine until the html page is open in one browser. when I open html page in another browser I face to this error:

```
The process cannot access the file 'video path' because it is being used by another process.
```

I want to be able show the video in multi browser at the same time.
thanks